# Image tiling causes some browsers to ignore overflow constraints

Tags: overflow

I created a set of small PNG files to hug the top and bottom of my website. By repeating themselves on the X-axis they span the entire width of the site and actively shrink and expand with the browser. This worked as predicted until the upper span was pushed to the right allowing another image (logo/button) to occupy the upper-left corner. This repeating image and the banner logo are a contiguous image so I'm doing my best to make it work as designed. I added this bit to my style sheet to nudge the repeating image over to the right:

```
    left:650px;
```

This caused a horizontal scroll-bar to appear allowing access to a big-open-nothing at the right side of my site (it appears to be the same distance the PNG is being pushed over to). I believe this is called overflow? To constrain the overflow I added the following to the html, body tag in the style sheet:

```
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
```

This removes the scroll-bar in all the browsers I've tested (Chrome, IE, FF & Opera) but in most cases, side scrolling can still be invoked by clicking down on the center mouse button and activating the easy-scroll feature (I don't know the actual name of this feature, but hope you understand what I mean).

FF deactivates this mouse feature but still allows scrolling with the keyboard arrows. IE is the only browser that is working correctly.

I've looked all over for an answer but have only netted some possible solutions, but I don't understand how to implement or even how to describe them. Being a novice I suspect incorrect terminology is also hindering my searches. In any case, if you take a peek at my website:

http://www.cybergolem.com/indexWIP.php

BTW, my div nesting looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <a class="homebutton" href="index.php">Home Page</a>
        <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> 
        <div id="footNote"> — Thar Be Dragons Here — </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks Much.